# Right - Align for TextBlock is not working in Silverlight

Tags: xaml, silverlight

```
<ContentControl Width="120">
<ContentControl.Content>
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="ABC" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</ContentControl.Content>
```

Please find the above code.

It's not getting right aligned.

Answer (score 2):

It is working, but `ContentControl` by default aligns it's content to the left with just enough place to show.

You can just set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to Right in ContentControl, so child don't have to worry about it:

```
<ContentControl Width="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
    <TextBlock Text="ABC" />
</ContentControl>
```

Or you can set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to Stretch and leave the rest for child to figure out:

```
<ContentControl Width="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="ABC" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</ContentControl>
```